# How to insert default values to the LMS databse of openedx

Tags: edx

I installed the Open edx Developer Stack. When I run the LMs or the Studio the databases of students data and courses data are empty.
How can I insert elements to the databases in order to work with them ?

Comment: follow this doc http://edx.readthedocs.org/projects/open-edx-building-and-running-a-course/en/latest/index.html
create a course, and attend it in LMS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And concerning data about students. Is there ay way to insert default values in mysql tables like auth_user Table, auth_userprofile Table...

Comment: You can sign up to your lms, so that user and user profile will be created.

Comment: Yes I m going to do that. Thank you.

Comment: edx related questions are better answered in their google group, check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/edx-code and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openedx-ops
and now they have slack too https://openedx.slack.com

Comment: thank you that will be usefull for me